# Is there any difference in Console.WriteLine("{0}, var); and MessageBox.Show("{0},var)

Tags: c#

Is there any error in the following statement?

```
var str = "Hello how are you.";
MessageBox.Show("{0}",str);
```

My problem was in the following code where I was not getting it correctly. The code below is part of learning process. In the MessageBox the 'designation' variable is not coming as I stated above! I originally posted it due to my ignorance that when I test something I can use the MessageBox like Console.WriteLine().

```
abstract class Employee //Abstract class
{
     public virtual void WhichCoEmployee()
     {
         MessageBox.Show("I am employed in XYZ Corporation as its {0}", designation); //My problem was in this line.
          //designation varaiable was not received in 
          //placeholder {0} for display in MessageBox.Show.
     }
     public void Designation(string desig)
     {
         designation = desig;
     }
     public string designation { get; set; }
}

class CEO : Employee //Inheritance
{
    public void Name()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My name is Satheeshkumar K");
    }
}

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     CEO ceo = new CEO(); //Initializing the CEO class.
     ceo.Name();
     ceo.Designation("CEO");   
     ceo.WhichCoEmployee();
 }
```

Subsequenly I have rectified the MessageBox.Show problem by changing the
the Message Box code.

```
MessageBox.Show("I am employed in XYZ Corporation as its " + designation);
```

That worked fine. I have nothing more to say on this. Being a member of the stackoverflow has really helped me to learn some things due to the help from other members.

Comment: you've got to provide more context

Comment: Please consider reading explanations of methods on MSDN before asking... It is very unclear how you expect to compare these two very different methods.

Comment: Okay. @Alexei Levenkov.

Comment: As a learner, these are practically my down-to-earth doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT:

Simply change

```
MessageBox.Show("I am employed in XYZ Corporation as its {0}", designation);
```

to

`MessageBox.Show("I am employed in XYZ Corporation as its " + designation`);

BTW, you need to call this method somewhere for the code to run!

---

No. Your two lines seems to be perfectly correct **according to the syntax**.

But it seems that what you are trying to achieve is something different than what you have done.. Here's the thing: You just called this overloaded version of `Show` method of `MessageBox` class, which accepts two strings.

```
public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption);
```

Hence in your case, a message box with "{0}" text and "Hello how are you." caption will be shown.

However, `Console.WriteLine("{0}", var);` is completely different. It is used to print output to the console. It also has many overloaded varieties, and in this case, it will replace {0} with the value of `var` variable. Hence, "Hello how are you." will be outputted to the Console.

Comment: Can you edit your existing answer?  Otherwise these should be comments.

Comment: I have solved the problem myself my changing/removing the placeholder. Changed it to MessageBox.Show("I am employed in XYZ Corporation as its " + designation); This worked fine for me. I could not immeidately respond as I was doing my physical exercise for 1.5 hours.  @John3136

Comment: Vijay Chavada's guidance did solve my problem. That is why I have upvoted it and marked it correct.  it opened my eyes to getting a resolution. I had been getting the answer as he pointed out i.e., the variable was appearing as the caption in the MessageBox. It is invalid to use the placeholder in the MessageBox.Show

Comment: @Unnikrishnan glad I could help..

Comment: I can't imagine. Without stackoverflow site, it would have taken me hours and hours to get to solve the problem.